# How to cite when I want to use a direct quote in the same sentence as an in-text citation with no parenthesis in APA?

Tags: citations, writing, formatting

For example, I want to describe a paper with a direct quote from it. Would this be OK:

Pieters and Wedel (2007) “revealed goal  control of attention even during a few seconds of self-paced ad exposure with an eye-tracking experiment” (Pieters & Wedel, 2007, p 224)

I use APA 6th edition as the guideline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is incorrect according to the [APA Style Blog](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2010/03/how-to-cite-direct-quotations.html). The correct way would be

> Pieters and Wedel (2007) “revealed goal control of attention even during a few seconds of self-paced ad exposure with an eye-tracking experiment” (p. 224)

NB: there is a period after the *p*.